# jQuery .slideToggle() repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

My jQuery Code is as follows:

```
$('.sidebar_options_arrow').click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('rel');
    toggled = 0;
    if(toggled == 0) {
        toggled = 1;
        $('#'+id+'-info').slideToggle('fast', function() {
            alert('1');
            toggled = 0;
        });
        $('.chat_sidebar_desc').not($('#'+id+'-info')).slideUp('fast');
    }
    return false;
});
$('#chat_sidebar ul li').click(function() {
    id2 = $(this).attr('rel');
    if(loading == 0) {
        loading = 1;
        $('#chat_main_container').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#loading').fadeIn(function() {
                if(id2 == 0) {
                    $('#chat_main_container').empty().load('chat/start.php');
                    $('#loading').delay(500).fadeOut(function() {
                        loading = 0;
                        $('#chat_main_container').fadeIn();
                    });
                }else{
                    $('#chat_main_container').empty().load('chat/index.php?roomid='+id2);
                    $('#loading').delay(500).fadeOut(function() {
                        loading = 0;
                        $('#chat_main_container').fadeIn();
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

The issue I'm having is as follows:

- I click sidebar_options_arrow and it works fine and slideToggle's my element.
- I then click an li on the same page and let it load a page.
- I click sidebar_options_arrow again and it toggles twice, one after another. E.g. in this example, it would toggle it to show the element then toggle it to hide it.
- If I then click another li on the page, and then click the sidebar_options_arrow again, it will toggle 3 times. It's an ongoing pattern, I've tested it to 10 toggled and confirmed it by making it alert something whenever it toggles.

I would really appreciate any help I can get on this, it's extremely annoying!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can put the case on jsfiddle.net .. I might be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very likely that your code above is running multiple times, probably from the AJAX load, meaning the `$('.sidebar_options_arrow').click()` code is getting an additional handler *each* time you do load.  To see this in action, simply add an `alert("binding");` above your first line: `$('.sidebar_options_arrow').click(function() {`.

The AJAX loaded content should not re-run handlers unless it needs to, as you see in this case it'll cause some unwanted duplicate/overlapping behavior because of each load adding a *new* set of the same handlers.

You'll want to move the JS portion out of the content you're loading so it doesn't re-run, or prevent it another way.  In the worst case (I recommend it not running at all, as that's cheaper, but if you *have* to....) you can simply call [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) before [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) when attaching the handler.  Note: if you have multiple handlers (potential user scripts, etc...anything here), you'll need to name that function and call [`.unbind("click", functionName)`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) explicitly to be safe.